# Getting session information from a xmmppy connection for jsjac

Tags: python, xmpppy

I am trying to make xwchat and xmpppy work together following this blog post , http://codingcromulence.blogspot.com/2009/01/chat-hacking-part-ii.html But unable to get session id and other information from xmpppy connection. Does anyone has prior experience with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, need to use a BOSH Client on server side, BOSH client creates a session and gives sid, rid which can be used in view.